# Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\foodpoint\welcome.php on line 205

Tags: php

Im getting this:

> Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\foodpoint\welcome.php on line 205

This is my the code on line 205:

```
<?php
$tot_tapas = number_format($number_of_persons, 2) * number_format($tapas, 2)
?>

<?php
$details = json_decode($obj->details);
$tapas = $number_of_persons = '';
foreach ($details->items as $item) {
    foreach ($item->extras as $extra) {
        // new
        $tapas = $item->service_price;
        $number_of_persons = $item->number_of_persons;
        // new
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col kolom1">
                <?php echo $extra->quantity; ?>x <?php echo $extra->title; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col kolom2">
                P/s : €<?php echo $extra->price; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col kolom3">
                <?php $total = $extra->quantity * $extra->price; ?>
                <?php echo '€' . number_format($total, 2); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <?php
        
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That message is telling you that `$number_of_persons` or `$tapas` is a string, not a float. Can you show the code where you define/assign `$number_of_persons` and `$tapas`?

Comment: Not sure why you are using `number_format()` here, perhaps you just want to make sure the two numbers are 2 decimals.

Comment: @kerbh0lz i will add it in the post

Comment: Please add PHP version you are using; definition of tapas, or at least from where are you getting it and describe briefly what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: a lot of times this warning happens because people forget to assign 0 when no number is put into a variable or wrap it in a conditional statement to ignore it when no variable exists.

Answer (score 7):

The error tells you that your first parameter of the `number_format()` function isn't a float (and it **should** be).

You have to cast the variable into float. You can do it with [floatval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) or by [direct casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

In your case, it is either `$number_of_persons` or `$tapas` or both

Comment: No you should use floatval on the first parameter of number_format(). Like this number_format(floatval($first_param), $second_param)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'number_format' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\foodpoint\welcome.php on line 205 still getting this

Comment: ```<?php $tot_tapas = number_format (floatval($number_of_persons, 2) * number_format($tapas, 2)?>```

Comment: @Marvin The _first_! parameter of number_format(): `number_format (floatval($number_of_persons), 2) * number_format(floatval($tapas), 2)`

Comment: You have miss one closing parenthesis, the right syntax is

<?php $tot_tapas = number_format (floatval($number_of_persons), 2) * number_format($tapas, 2)?>

Comment: And to be sure, it could be the second call of number_format too, so it'll be safer this way : <?php $tot_tapas = number_format (floatval($number_of_persons), 2) * number_format(floatval($tapas), 2)?>

Comment: Thank you for that, now the second problem starts... BTW Sorry for all this but im in my second year of software dev and im on a internship atm so that why im asking so much. but i get now this: Notice: Undefined variable: tot_tapas in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\foodpoint\welcome.php on line 214 with this code on that line: ```        <?php echo '€'. number_format(floatval($tot_tapas, 2) ?>
```

Comment: @Marvin, all the error that you're showing us are quite explicit. If you're not natively speaking English, you can easily translate them with any online translator. It should help you directly.

Comment: Yea ok. But im pretty new to php so thats why im asking it here.

Comment: This is all working now so everyone thanks for that. But i have 1 other question.Undefined variable: arrx in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\foodpoint\print.php on line 147 ```foreach($arrx as $obj) {```

Comment: @Marvin Please post a new question then

Comment: @kerbh0lz i posted it This is all working now so everyone thanks for that. But i have 1 other question.Undefined variable: arrx in D:\xampp\htdocs\website\foodpoint\print.php on line 147 ```foreach($arrx as $obj) {```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the variables has numbers as a value, then you can do this:

```
$tot_tapas = number_format((int) $number_of_persons, 2)  * number_format((int) $tapas, 2)
```

The magic is type juggling, where you cast it to int. Read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

But instead you should just make sure the variables is of type integer and doesn't have a string value.

```
$number_of_persons = 4;
$tapas = 2; 
// => OK

$number_of_persons = "4";
$tapas = "two tapas 2"; 
// => Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use floatval().
but i think you can find which one is not float number_of_persons or tapas. use gettype() and see which one is string and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the variables has numbers as a value, then you can do this:

```
$tot_tapas = float($number_of_persons) * float($tapas);
$tot_tapas = number_format((float)$tot_tapas , 2, '.', '');
```